# How can i do plot 3D cluster for RFM analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, data-analysis

I have a Customer Segmentation with RFM Analysis project. I divided the customers into groups like 'Cant loose Them','Loyals','Champions' by RFM Level. There are 7 different groups.

I need 3D plot of clusters. I  have a [Example 3D Plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjUgg.png) by Frequency,Recency,Monetary but it has 3 different clusters. I need 7 different clusters. So how can i do 3D plot of RFM levels ?

[Photo of my Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvdNV.png)

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly as py

x3 = data[['R_Quartile','F_Quartile','M_Quartile']].iloc[:,:].values 

algorithm = (KMeans(n_clusters = 3 ,init='k-means++', n_init = 10 ,max_iter=300, 
                        tol=0.0001,  random_state= 111  , algorithm='elkan') )
algorithm.fit(x3)
labels3 = algorithm.labels_
centroids3 = algorithm.cluster_centers_

data['label3'] =  labels3
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x= data['recency'],
    y= data['frequency'],
    z= data['monetary'],
    mode='markers',
     marker=dict(
        color = data['label3'], 
        size= 1,
        line=dict(
            color= data['label3'],
            width= 12
        ),
        opacity=0.8
     )
)
data_temp = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
#     margin=dict(
#         l=0,
#         r=0,
#         b=0,
#         t=0
#     )
    title= 'Clusters',
    scene = dict(
            xaxis = dict(title  = 'R'),
            yaxis = dict(title  = 'F'),
            zaxis = dict(title  = 'M')
        )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data_temp, layout=layout)
py.offline.iplot(fig)
```